# Are comments being favored over answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

**Scenario:**

I've noticed while skimming through questions on CodeReview that people are replying with legitimate answers in the comments section, instead of the answers section.

While I've only attached 2 links below, I think if you surf around enough you will see what I mean.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10267/meta-question-although-i-havent-the-reputation-is-it-generally-a-good-idea-to

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/find-the-largest-prime-factor-of-the-number-600851475143

**Feature Request:**

Allow a comment to be promoted (migrated) to an answer.  Include the option to auto-accept as the answer for the question.

**Comments:**

Other than helping to clarify that the comments are "clarifications", I don't see why we would need to break the implicit flow of what the users do.  Just add in the workflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a comment on that question because I was mostly just pointing out the footer text, and I thought others would have better insight (and I was right).

I think, for the most part, people add a comment instead of an answer because they want to or because they feel it doesn't qualify as a full answer. If the OP wants to accept the comment as an answer, he can add a comment asking to post it as an answer, or he can just add an answer which quotes the comment.

And FYI this feature has [already been requested on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question).

Comment: Thanks seand. I didn't see this feature request, which is why I added it.